# Tailwind table overflow-x-auto doesn't work

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I made the table like below.

And I put `overflow-x-auto` not to squeeze all the contents but just make scroll.

```
 <table className="border-collapse overflow-x-auto">
                    <tbody className="overflow-x-auto">
                        <tr>
                            <th className="border-b-2 border-slate-700 justify-center items-center px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">순위</th>
                            <th className="border-b-2 border-slate-700 justify-center items-center px-5 py-2 text-left text-sm">이름</th>
                            <th className="border-b-2 border-slate-700 justify-center items-center px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">나이</th>
                            <th className="border-b-2 border-slate-700 justify-center items-center px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">출생년도</th>
                            <th className="border-b-2 border-slate-700 justify-center items-center px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">생일</th>
                            <th className="border-b-2 border-slate-700 justify-center items-center px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">성별</th>
                            <th className="border-b-2 border-slate-700 justify-center items-center px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">핸드폰 번호</th>
                            <th className="border-b-2 border-slate-700 justify-center items-center px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">거주 지역</th>
                            <th className="border-b-2 border-slate-700 justify-center items-center px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">소속 기관</th>
                            <th className="border-b-2 border-slate-700 justify-center items-center px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">점수</th>
                            <th className="border-b-2 border-slate-700 justify-center items-center px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">일상</th>
                            <th className="border-b-2 border-slate-700 justify-center items-center px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">시</th>
                            <th className="border-b-2 border-slate-700 justify-center items-center px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">댓글</th>
                            <th className="border-b-2 border-slate-700 justify-center items-center px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">좋아요</th>
                        </tr> 
                       { loading ? data.map((item, index) => tablemap(item, index)) : null}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

However as you can see below,
it squeezes all the contents and not make scroll.

I also apply `overflow-x-auto` to top parent div as well.

But also doens't work.

what is the problem?

[image]

Comment: table should have fixed width or element should not wrapping or there should not be enough space even when wrapped. As a variant, add `whitespace-nowrap` and `overflow-x-auto` to a parent div, like [this](https://play.tailwindcss.com/x1AAFhHnWb) if ifs OK for your task

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
You can control the width with w-screen(Full screen) or w-[90vw](90% device width)

```
<div className="w-screen overflow-y-hidden overflow-x-scroll">
    <table className="border-collapse">
      <tbody className="">
        <tr>
          <th className="items-center justify-center border-b-2 border-slate-700 px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">
            순위
          </th>
          <th className="items-center justify-center border-b-2 border-slate-700 px-5 py-2 text-left text-sm">
            이름
          </th>
          <th className="items-center justify-center border-b-2 border-slate-700 px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">
            나이
          </th>
          <th className="items-center justify-center border-b-2 border-slate-700 px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">
            출생년도
          </th>
          <th className="items-center justify-center border-b-2 border-slate-700 px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">
            생일
          </th>
          <th className="items-center justify-center border-b-2 border-slate-700 px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">
            성별
          </th>
          <th className="items-center justify-center border-b-2 border-slate-700 px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">
            핸드폰 번호
          </th>
          <th className="items-center justify-center border-b-2 border-slate-700 px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">
            거주 지역
          </th>
          <th className="items-center justify-center border-b-2 border-slate-700 px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">
            소속 기관
          </th>
          <th className="items-center justify-center border-b-2 border-slate-700 px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">
            점수
          </th>
          <th className="items-center justify-center border-b-2 border-slate-700 px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">
            일상
          </th>
          <th className="items-center justify-center border-b-2 border-slate-700 px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">
            시
          </th>
          <th className="items-center justify-center border-b-2 border-slate-700 px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">
            댓글
          </th>
          <th className="items-center justify-center border-b-2 border-slate-700 px-5 py-1 text-left text-sm">
            좋아요
          </th>
        </tr>
        { loading ? data.map((item, index) => tablemap(item, index)) : null}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```